# Lista de comandos io.popen en Lua

Tags: lua

¿Cuáles son los comandos (no los modos) que puedo usar con `io.popen` en Lua?

```lua
output = io.popen(command)
```

---

En realidad busco la manera de pasar un argumento de ruta de archivo pero en una variable no en un string, o sea no:

```lua
io.popen(dir,"C:\myfile.txt", /b)
```

sino algo como:

```
local mypath = "C:\myfile.txt"
io.popen(dir,mypath, /b)
```

pero no me funciona. Lo que realmente busco es abrir un directorio y copiar los archivos que hay dentro, pero no sé el nombre del directorio, así que obtengo la ruta al directorio y la almaceno en una variable que luego paso a `io.popen`, pero parece que no quiere variable, solo texto, o más bien que yo lo estoy haciendo mal.

Este es el comando que utilizo actualmente:

```
for dir1 in io.popen("dir " ..filepath2[i] .." /b"):lines() do table.insert(h, dir1) end
```

**filepath2** es una tabla que contiene todas las rutas (son varios directorios) y lo estoy iterando mediante un bucle `for` y le envío a `io.popen` cada ruta de directorio.
Lo que busco es que `io.open` me liste todos las rutas de que hay dentro de cada directorio, en una tabla. Ejemplo:

```
C:\audio\musica
```

Digamos que la carpeta *musica* contiene 10 archivos de audio, así que el archivo de texto resultante, debería listar los 10 archivos de audio, algo como:

```
C:\audio\musica\mi cancion1.mp3
C:\audio\musica\mi cancion2.mp3
```

y así sucesivamente.

Lo que pasa es que no me funciona; yo he observado en todos los ejemplos, que la gente pone un string en la ruta de archivo, nunca una variable, así que ¿cómo se hace?